# Azure DevOps Docker Task with multiple tags

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I hate Azure DevOps, but I'm stuck using it.....  They have a `Docker@2` task that has this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml#inputs:%7E:text=the%20Docker%20file.-,tags,-%2D%20Tags%0Astring)

> string. Optional. Use when command = build || command = push || command = buildAndPush. Default value: $(Build.BuildId). Specifies a list of tags on separate lines. These tags are used in build, push and buildAndPush commands.

specifically -> **Specifies a list of tags on separate lines.**

anybody able to get this working?

I tried:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: build and push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: <my-registry-connection>
    repository: <my-repo-name>
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    tags: 
      - latest
      - $(Build.SourceVersion)
```

which failed with

> /build-pipeline.yml (Line: 20, Col: 7): A sequence was not expected

and

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: build and push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: <my-registry-connection>
    repository: <my-repo-name>
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    tags: 
      latest
      $(Build.SourceVersion)
```

which failed with:

> invalid argument "***/my-repo-name:my-commit latest" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format

Answer (score 3):

I guess `separate lines` means different things to different people:

this works:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: build and push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: <my-registry>
    repository: <my-repository>
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    tags: latest,$(Build.SourceVersion)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work (note the "|"):

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: build and push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: <my-registry>
    repository: <my-repository>
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    tags: |
      latest
      $(Build.SourceVersion)
```